# PATH doesn't work on Windows 8 RC x64

Tags: windows, 64-bit, path, windows-8-preview

...or I just don't know how to make it work :)

[image: Screenshot]

You can see the folder IS in the path variable, hower I can't execute hg, which is inside the folder.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space between the `;` and the start of `C:\Program Files\TortoiseHq`.  Get rid of the space and it will work.